Problem with QPixmap in Qt library for c++
I'm trying to load an image into a QPixmap object, here is my code:
QPixmap blackKingPixmap;
std::cout << "Hello";
blackKingPixmap.load("images/black_king.png");
std::cout << "Hello";

When I run it, I only see one 'Hello' printed to the console, shortly after that the program terminates without printing the second 'Hello'.
I don't get any error messages when I run it, it simply just terminates.
I have tried the following:

putting the 'images' folder in the 'resources' folder, and in the same folder as the .cpp file;
taking the images out of the folder and putting them directly in the 'resources' folder;
specifying the absolute path to the image ('C:/ etcetc');
I even tried loading the image to a QImage first and then trying to create the QPixmap from the QImage;

I have checked that the image definitely exists at the specified path, and that the permissions for accessing the image are correct.
All of which to no avail!
Basically I have tried everything that I could think of to fix it, none of it worked.
Edit: Providing a minimal reproducible example.
main.cpp:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPixmap blackKingPixmap;
    
    blackKingPixmap.load("images/black_king.png");

    QLabel label;
    label.setPixmap(blackKingPixmap);
    label.show();

    return app.exec();
}


main.pro:

CONFIG += c++11 console

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main

QT = core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES +=  main.cpp


On the command line I run:
qmake
make
release\main

And the program crashes. I am running on command prompt and I am using the latest version of Mingw as my c++ compiler.
Also please note that when I comment out the .load(path) line on the first example, the whole program runs fine, and the window is displayed (just without the image on it).
Edit 2:
I changed my code in the following way:

QPixmap Chess_GUI::loadPixmap(const QString &filePath) {
    std::cout << "1";
    QImageReader reader(filePath);
    std::cout << "2";
    QImage image = reader.read();
    std::cout << "3";
    if (image.isNull()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load image: " << filePath.toStdString() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "4";
    return QPixmap::fromImage(image);
}

void Chess_GUI::loadImages() {
    blackKingPixmap = loadPixmap("images/black_king.png");
    std::cout << "5";

    // More function calls here
}

When I run this it prints '1234', but it doesn't print the '5'. So it loads the image fine, but it just can't convert it to a QPixmap.
Edit:
Thanks everyone for your responses, the problem is solved now, the issue was either something to do with returning QPixmaps / QImages, or passing QStrings as parameters.

Note that QPixmap requires an existing instance of QGuiApplication (or QApplication) in order to be properly constructed. Does the Qt application exist when the above lines are executed? Also note that QPixmaps should always be created in the Qt application thread: you're not trying to execute the above from an external thread, are you? Please [edit] your question to provide a proper [mre] and relevant environment info, including specific OS/Qt versions, building/IDE specifications, and any debugging output you get (including testing on a terminal or prompt).

Some other things you could have thought of: running your code in a debugger so you see whether the process crashes or just completes silently. Checking the return code of QPixmap::load. Checking the run configuration of your project to see what the current working directory is set to. Embedding the resource into your Qt project and referring to it that way to avoid path issues. Providing an [mre].

@musicamante Thanks for your response. I am running the code inside of a QWidget. I provided a minimal reproducible example.

@Botje Thanks for your response. I tried checking the return code of load, but the problem is that it doesn't return anything, it just crashes, so this didn't work. I will try the other things you mentioned. I also provided a minimal reproducible example.

@musicamante I forgot to mention, there is an instance a QApplication in main, just like in the example.

Use a debugger so you get actual information about the crash. Your print statements are not telling you anything you don't know already.

@Botje So I ran it with gdb, and there was something called a SIGTRAP. I ran this command:
handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint
And then the whole thing executed perfectly. I still can't get it to work in the release version though.

Try QImageReader to make sure image is not corrupted.
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <iostream>
#include <QImageReader>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString path = "images/black_king.png";
    if (!QFile::exists(path)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Error", "File does not exist");
        return 1;
    }

    QImageReader reader(path);
    QImage image = reader.read();

    if (image.isNull()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Error", reader.errorString());
        return 1;
    }

    QPixmap blackKingPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

    QLabel label;
    label.setPixmap(blackKingPixmap);
    label.show();

    return app.exec();
}


Hi, I'm actually still having issues with my code, if you wouldn't mind could you please take a look at the second edit that I made? I made a separate project and ran the code that you provided and the image showed up fine, but when I try to add it to my project it crashes.

@Michael You might not need QPixmap at all, you can do almost anything with QImage instead of a pixmap.
